# Map and Index foreign key in MongoDb using C# Driver Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Giving the model listed below I want to create an IndexKey for property PostId using MongoDb.Driver.Serialization.

```
    public class Post
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; private set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Comment
    {

        public ObjectId Id { get; private set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }

        public ObjectId PostId { get; set; }

        public Post Post { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to use something similar like this

```
    MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Post>(p =>
    {
        p.MapIdField(f => f.Id);
    });
```

Comment: There's not. People have solved it a few different ways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823187/how-to-decorate-a-class-item-to-be-an-index-and-get-the-same-as-using-ensureinde

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to apply an index to that property you should use [CreateIndex](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.1/html/1f6e0b1a-ff81-8ebc-d8ae-63d46e7fdf70.htm) 
Foreign key is not really a part of NoSQL and MongoDB. It can't really enforce that rule in the same way an SQL database would.

Example:

```
_databaseClient.GetServer().GetDatabase("database").
    GetCollection<Comment>("Comments").CreateIndex(
        IndexKeys<Comment>.Ascending(_ => _.PostId ));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that's not the goal of NoSQL databases but mongodb has a limitation 0f 16mb (not sure) per document and base on that limitation sometimes is save to de-normailze de data. My question was if there is a way of use EnsureIndex using the mapping capabilities inside the  Serialization namespace of the driver.

Comment: I don't think so. Also, why would you care if it's under `MongoDb.Driver.Serialization` or just `MongoDB.Driver`

Comment: Sorry by the late reply. Inside the Serialization namespace there is a map class call RegisterClassMap this class allow to map db field to database field, I was wondering is there is a way using a class like to tell mongodb that a particular field is a index field. Similar to fluent api in entity framework

Comment: Serialization defines how to turn your objects to documents. Adding an index is an action that you perform on the Database itself. Serialization wouldn't really be the right place for that action.

Comment: I've written something similar before where you decorated the class with `Index` attributes, each attrib represented an index to be built on the database.  I had a "build indexes" function that used reflection to iterate through classes decorated with the `index` attribute and used the mongodb driver to ensure they existed.